# What is the biblical basis for the concept of "activating", "triggering", or "igniting" God's promises?

Tags: biblical-basis, faith, blessings, promises

The concept can be found in several Christian sources:

- [GOD’S PROMISES AREN’T AUTOMATED, THEY’RE ACTIVATED](https://www.redeemercoast.church/blog/2021/1/22/gods-promises-arent-automated-theyre-activated)
- [3 Keys to Activating God’s Promises in Your Life](https://faithisland.org/bible/3-keys-to-activating-gods-promises-in-your-life/)
- [Activating the Promises of God: Unlock the Power of the Bible & Empower Your Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CR31XPYS)
- *"Perhaps they did not believe that such a simple action could **trigger the promised healing**. Or perhaps they willfully hardened their hearts and rejected the counsel of God’s prophet."*

  *"The principle of **activating** blessings that flow from God is eternal.* [...] *In fact, it can be seen in heaven because small acts of faith are required to **ignite God’s promises**."*

  *"I invite you to faithfully **activate heavenly power to receive specific blessings from God**. Exercise the faith to strike the match and light the fire. Supply the needed oxygen while you patiently wait on the Lord. With these invitations, I pray that the Holy Ghost will guide and direct you so that you, like the faithful person described in Proverbs, will “abound with blessings.” I testify that your Heavenly Father and His Beloved Son, Jesus Christ, live, are concerned with your welfare, and delight to bless you, in the name of Jesus Christ, amen."* (source: [Abound with Blessings](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2019/04/41renlund?lang=eng))

For those who teach the idea of "activating" God's promises, what Biblical support do they see for this, and what conditions and nuances are delineated concerning the promises that can be "activated," "triggered," or "ignited"? In exploring this concept, I seek to understand the scriptural teachings regarding the dynamic relationship between faith and the realization of divine promises. What specific conditions or principles does the Bible outline for believers who seek to actively engage their faith to unlock, set in motion, or bring to fruition the promises bestowed by God?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 7 Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you:
>
> 8 For every one that asketh receiveth; and he that seeketh findeth; and to him that knocketh it shall be opened. (Matthew 7:7-8)

There is no such promise associated with not asking, not seeking, and not knocking.

God isn't simply looking for our intellectual assent; He wants to change our nature.

The great miracle of this plan is not that God creates something that does what He wants it to do, but that He can take someone that does *not* do what He wants them to do, and develop, teach, lead, and coach them to do as He does *of their own volition*, and that for those willing to walk that path, He has promised:

> but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is. And every man that hath this hope in him purifieth himself, even as he is pure. (1 John 3:2a-3)

Comment: "of their own volition"  Can you expand on this in light of Philippians 2:13 so that salvation doesn't appear to be based on works to be boasted in?

Comment: @MikeBorden Fair point.  The only real act of the will with respect to God isn't doing something, it's ceasing to do something, i.e. to cease being a rebel and to surrender.